# ERROR ... Sketch el espacio de almacenamiento de programa

Tags: arduino

Realicé mi primer proyecto para hacer parpadear un led y funcionó.

Al intentar borra el proyecto anterior y realiza uno nuevo me resulta imposible siempre me sale en mismo error. Ya habilité el puerto CMO.

```
El Sketch usa 444 bytes (1%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 32256 bytes.
```

Las variables Globales usan 9 bytes (0%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 2039 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2048 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Ese no es un error; es el resultado de la compilación informandote de espacio requerido. Dato importante dado que sólo tienes 2KB de RAM para data.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que deseas es utilizar un simulador como Proteus para ver el funcionamiento del programa, lo único que debes hacer es ir a la barra del menú, en programa, exportar binarios combinados. Luego vas a Proteus, das doble click en tu Arduino y buscas la ubicación del programa que utilizarás y aparecerá el archivo .hex

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

AYUDA!! ME APARECE ESTE ERROR AL CARGAR EL CODIGO EN MI ARDUINO UNO

El Sketch usa 1786 bytes (5%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 32256 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 50 bytes (2%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 1998 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2048 bytes.
**avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM7": Acceso denegado.**

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).